# How to test a variable is set, not null and has a particular value

Tags: php

I have a problem.
I have made a php code for selecting data by checking a value from one textbox. If value is exist it will use a function that I made. I don't know why my code won't work.
I have tried to change and change my code and still it does not work.

This is my code-

```html
<?php
include("../../Connections/koneksi.php");

$date_awal=$_POST['date_start'];
$date_akhir=$_POST['date_end'];
$kode=$_POST['kode_mat'];
$kode_mat=$_POST['kode_mat1'];
$sloc=$_POST['s_loc'];
$s_loc=$_POST['s_loc1'];
$type=$_POST['get_type'];

//Display all data
$rows = array();

if($date_awal != '' && $kode != '' && isset($type)== '-' ){
 //data with input date_awal and kode
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM wjm WHERE date='$date_awal' AND kode='$kode' AND uses IN ('Borongan','Tilting') order by date,kode asc";
}else if ( $date_awal != '' && isset($type)== '-' ){
 //data with input date_awal
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM wjm WHERE date='$date_awal' AND uses IN ('Borongan','Tilting') order by date,kode asc ";
}else if ($date_awal !='' && isset($type)== 'all'){
 //data with input date_awal and type=all
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM wjm WHERE date='$date_awal' AND uses IN ('Borongan','Tilting') order by date,kode asc ";
}else if ($date_awal !='' && isset($type)== 'report'){
 //data with input date_awal and type=report
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM wjm WHERE date='$date_awal' AND uses IN ('Borongan') order by date,kode asc ";
}else{
 //data no input
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM wjm WHERE uses IN ('Borongan','Tilting') ORDER by date,kode asc";
}

$query = mysqli_query($db,$sql);

while($tmp= mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    $rows[] = $tmp;
}

echo json_encode($rows);

mysqli_close($db);
?>
```

the eror is when i set value on `$type` as `report` it still render at the function  with `$type "-" and "all"`

Comment: `isset($type)` will never return `-`. http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php `Returns TRUE if var exists and has value other than NULL. FALSE otherwise.`

Comment: @chris85 it mean when `isset(type)` has a value always say it is true?

Comment: Yes, it is `true` or `false`.

Comment: You could do `isset($type) && $type == ` if you want to also compare its value when is set.

Comment: @chris85 when it will check it has a value it will always return true. hmmm...
chris how i can check my textbox has a value same with the value that i set in my if condition? 
can i use something like this? `$date_awal != ''` and i set a value inside them

Comment: Does my last comment answer that?

Comment: @chris85 ehehehhe. im not refresh the page and i have slow connection

Comment: @chris85 thx for your suggest.
i learn something. when i use `isset` i must make one more parameter for checking the val

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use isset to check not null and apply condition to $type, as   @chris85  you cannot combine the conditions:

```
<?php
include("../../Connections/koneksi.php");

$date_awal=$_POST['date_start'];
$date_akhir=$_POST['date_end'];
$kode=$_POST['kode_mat'];
$kode_mat=$_POST['kode_mat1'];
$sloc=$_POST['s_loc'];
$s_loc=$_POST['s_loc1'];
$type=$_POST['get_type'];

//Display all data
$rows = array();

if($date_awal != '' && $kode != '' && isset($type) &&$type== '-' ){
 //data with input date_awal and kode
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM wjm WHERE date='$date_awal' AND kode='$kode' AND uses IN ('Borongan','Tilting') order by date,kode asc";
}else if ( $date_awal != '' && isset($type) &&$type == '-' ){
 //data with input date_awal
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM wjm WHERE date='$date_awal' AND uses IN ('Borongan','Tilting') order by date,kode asc ";
}else if ($date_awal !='' && isset($type) && $type== 'all'){
 //data with input date_awal and type=all
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM wjm WHERE date='$date_awal' AND uses IN ('Borongan','Tilting') order by date,kode asc ";
}else if ($date_awal !='' && isset($type) && $type== 'report'){
 //data with input date_awal and type=report
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM wjm WHERE date='$date_awal' AND uses IN ('Borongan') order by date,kode asc ";
}else{
 //data no input
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM wjm WHERE uses IN ('Borongan','Tilting') ORDER by date,kode asc";
}

$query = mysqli_query($db,$sql);

while($tmp= mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    $rows[] = $tmp;
}

echo json_encode($rows);

mysqli_close($db);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You check function

> isset ()

Try to use the function

> empty()
>
> !empty()
>
> strlen($var)>0

Because $type is always isset, empty or full... isset() will return always true.